# Is it possible to get values from a for loop into a list?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to make a program to break a Hill Cipher with a known Key Matrix, and when I enter the ciphertext, and convert the letters into numbers, I use this for loop:

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

ciphertext = input('Enter your ciphertext')
ciphertext = list(ciphertext.lower())

for symbol in ciphertext:
        num = int(letters.find(symbol))
        print(num)
```

and I am wondering if there is a way to transfer the numbers that are printed into an array, which I am using to represent the matrices that are involved in Hill ciphers, as I need to insert every block of 2 letters into a 2x1 matrix, in order to perform a matrix multiplication on each, in order to get the plaintext.

Basically, I am trying to get the numbers from the for loop into arrays, in the most efficient way possible, but I am very new to coding in python, so I have no idea how I would do it.

Also, is there just an easier way altogether to use matrices in python that I don't know about that would make this whole thing easier?

Comment: You don't need to do `list(ciphertext.lower())`. Strings are already iterables. `for symbol in ciphertext.lower()` will iterate over the characters in `ciphertext.lower()`.

Comment: Could you give an example, how you want your data to be represented exactly?

Comment: You also don't need to do `int(letters.find(symbol))`. `find()` already returns an integer.

Comment: Is `letters` always `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`?

Comment: @J Smith: what if the length of `ciphertext` is odd ?

Comment: Yes, the letters will always just be the alphabet

Comment: Why not `import string letters = string.ascii_lowercase`?

Comment: @JSmith So, always `a-z`? As in, the string, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"?

Comment: Just a note, since nobody properly answered your question(list comprehension might work here, but it's not a general solution and you'll just get stuck the next time you need a list). Create a list: `number_list = []`. Then just add to it: `number_list.append(letters.find(symbol))`

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ If the ciphertext is an odd length, it will just fill the blank spaces of the matrices with letters in alphabetical order

Comment: @AlekseiMaide I want to store the input (the ciphertext) in a series of arrays, with 2 letters in each one, e.g. if the ciphertext was 'abcd', the program will store the values 0,1,2,3 in arrays

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to return the character's ASCII values in a list. You can do this in linear time with a list comprehension.

```
symbols = 'axy12c'
```

```
lst = [ord(c) - ord('a') if c.isalpha() and c.islower() else -1 for c in symbols]

print(lst)
[0, 23, 24, -1, -1, 2]
```

---

Since you mention arrays, there's also a numpy way of doing this, lo and behold.

```
arr = np.array(list(symbols), dtype='|S1').view(np.int8) - 97
arr[(0 > arr) | (25 < arr)] = -1

print(arr)
array([ 0, 23, 24, -1, -1,  2], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: Oh. I've been slightly out numpy'd with `dtype` + `view` to avoid mapping `ord` in Python.

Comment: @BaileyParker I can still respect the effort you've put into writing your answer, so I upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use a list comprehension for this:

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
ciphertext = input().lower()

indices = [letters.find(c) for c in ciphertext]
```

This will append `letters.find(c)` to indices for each letter (called `c` here) in `ciphertext`.

But if `letters` is always the alphabet (and it seems like according to the wikipedia it is), you can make this faster by using `ord` which gives you the ASCII index of each letter. To make it so `'a'` is `0` you can just subtract `ord('a')`:

```
ciphertext = input().lower()
indices = [ord(c) - ord('a') for c in ciphertext]
```

Looking at the Wikipedia for a Hill Cipher, it looks like what you've described isn't exactly what you need.

My understanding is your key must be a perfect square in length (n^2). You then shape the key into a `n` by `n` matrix and multiply it by `n` chunks of the plaintext. You should look into [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/). It has tons of tools for working with matrices and I'm pretty sure you can express this cipher in a few lines:

```
import numpy as np

ciphertext = np.array(map(ord, input().lowercase())) - ord('a')
n = int(sqrt(len(ciphertext)))
assert n**2 == len(ciphertext), 'ciphertext must be perfect square in length'

ciphertext.reshape((n, n))  # Make ciphertext a nxn matrix
# Matrix multiply plaintext chunks of n by ciphertext
plaintext.reshape((n, -1)) @ ciphertext
```

It also seems like ciphertext must be invertible. numpy [allows you to check that the ciphertext is invertible (and compute its inverse)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html) without having to code out the linalg stuff yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get them into a list.

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
ciphertext = input('Enter your ciphertext')
ciphertext = list(ciphertext.lower())
desiredArray = list(map(lambda x: int(letters.find(x)), ciphertext))
```

This defines your lookup and conversion to an integer as a "lambda" function; the "map" function maps the lambda function to the elements of your ciphertext, and the "list" function casts the result as a list. These are all bits of python worth learning about.

Comment: `map(letters.find, input().lower())` should be fine

Comment: Bailey Parker's answer is neater, though